# Unable to get MySQL Utilities (mysqlrpladmin) to work properly under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I currently have replication running between 1 master and 2 slave servers. When I attempt to run mysqlrpladmin using the "--discover-slaves-login" option and "health" command, it only returns the health of the master server and doesn't list the slave servers, as shown below.

```
# Replication Topology Health:
+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+---------+
| host       | port  | role    | state  | gtid_mode  | health  |
+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+---------+
| localhost  | 3306  | MASTER  | UP     | ON         | OK      |
+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+---------+
```

For some reason, the mysqlrpladmin tool isn't picking up the slave servers. Instead, it attempts to connect to the master twice and I get the following message.

```
WARNING: Cannot connect to some slaves:
 - 192.168.56.101:3306: Server '192.168.56.101:3306' is not acting as a slave (slave status is empty).
 - 192.168.56.101:3306: Server '192.168.56.101:3306' is not acting as a slave (slave status is empty).
```

192.168.56.101 is the master. It appears that the two attempts to connect to the slaves are actually being issued on the master (once for each of the slaves connected).

Is there a configuration parameter in my.cnf or another config file that is causing this?

Side note... although this is happening, replication is running just fine.